Spring Cloud Gateway and NTLM Authentication
Is there a way to authenticate routes with NTLM Authentication in a GatewayFilter?
I took as a reference the ExchangeFilterFunction from this question which works perfectly with WebClient but I couldn't make it work in Spring Cloud Gateway.
For the GatewayFilter I took as a reference the WebClientHttpRoutingFilter which utilizes a WebClient.
It returns a 200 OK but the client call hangs.
GatewayFilter
@Component
public class NtlmAuthenticationGatewayFilter
        extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<NtlmAuthenticationGatewayFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

            //URI requestUrl = exchange.getRequiredAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR); //this is null for some reason in GatewayFilters

            Route route = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR);
            PathContainer pathContainer = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_PREDICATE_PATH_CONTAINER_ATTR);

            URI requestUrl = null;
            try {
                requestUrl = new URI(route.getUri() + pathContainer.value());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            String scheme = requestUrl.getScheme();
            if (isAlreadyRouted(exchange) || (!"http".equals(scheme) && !"https".equals(scheme))) {
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            }
            setAlreadyRouted(exchange);

            HttpMethod method = request.getMethod();

            boolean preserveHost = exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(PRESERVE_HOST_HEADER_ATTRIBUTE, false);

            WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().filter(new NtlmExchangeFilterFunction(config.getDomain(),
                    config.getUsername(), config.getPassword())).build();

            WebClient.RequestBodySpec bodySpec = webClient
                    .method(method)
                    .uri(requestUrl)
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                        if (!preserveHost) {
                            httpHeaders.remove(HttpHeaders.HOST);
                        }
                    });

            WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> headersSpec = bodySpec.body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(request.getBody()));

            return headersSpec.exchangeToMono(Mono::just)
                    .flatMap(res -> {
                        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                        response.getHeaders().putAll(res.headers().asHttpHeaders());
                        response.setStatusCode(res.statusCode());
                        // Defer committing the response until all route filters have run
                        // Put client response as ServerWebExchange attribute and write
                        // response later NettyWriteResponseFilter
                        exchange.getAttributes().put(CLIENT_RESPONSE_ATTR, res);
                        return chain.filter(exchange);
                    });
        };
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class Config {

        String domain;
        String username;
        String password;
    }
}

ExchangeFilterFunction
public class NtlmExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    private final NtlmPasswordAuthentication ntlmPasswordAuthentication;

    public NtlmExchangeFilterFunction(String domain, String username, String password) {
        this.ntlmPasswordAuthentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

        final NtlmContext ctxt = new NtlmContext(ntlmPasswordAuthentication, true);

        final byte[] token1 = ntlm(ctxt, new byte[0]);

        final ClientRequest ntlmChallenge = ClientRequest.from(request)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "NTLM ".concat(Base64.encode(token1)))
                .build();

        return next
                .exchange(ntlmChallenge)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    byte[] token2 = ntlm(ctxt, Base64.decode(extractNtlmHeaderValue(clientResponse)));
                    return next.exchange(ClientRequest.from(request)
                            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "NTLM ".concat(Base64.encode(token2)))
                            .build());
                });
    }

    private byte[] ntlm(NtlmContext ctxt, byte[] token) {
        try {
            return ctxt.initSecContext(token, 0, token.length);
        } catch (SmbException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String extractNtlmHeaderValue(ClientResponse response) {
        return response
                .headers()
                .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE).get(0).replace("NTLM ", "");

    }
}

The second option is to try to adjust ExchangeFilterFuction's logic to the GatewayFilter but I'm not sure how it can be done. I don't know how to pass the second token to the request.
GatewayFilter (adjusted)
@Component
public class NtlmAuthenticationGatewayFilter 
        extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<NtlmAuthenticationGatewayFilter.Config> {
    
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(NtlmAuthenticationGatewayFilter.Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {

        final NtlmContext ctxt = new NtlmContext(new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(config.getDomain(),
                config.getUsername(), config.getPassword()), true);

        final byte[] token1 = ntlm(ctxt, new byte[0]);

        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders
                        .add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "NTLM ".concat(Base64.encode(token1)))).build();

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build())
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                .then(Mono.defer(() -> {
                    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                    byte[] token2 = ntlm(ctxt, Base64.decode(extractNtlmHeaderValue(response)));

                    ServerHttpRequest request2 = exchange.getRequest().mutate().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                            "NTLM ".concat(Base64.encode(token2))).build();

                    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request2).build());
                }));
        };
    }

    private byte[] ntlm(NtlmContext ctxt, byte[] token) {
        try {
            return ctxt.initSecContext(token, 0, token.length);
        } catch (SmbException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String extractNtlmHeaderValue(ServerHttpResponse response) {
        return response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE).get(0).replace("NTLM ", "");
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class Config {

        String domain;
        String username;
        String password;
    }

}

Any ideas?
